# get TextFrom MimeMultipart Java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Can someone explain me this function?

```
    private String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException{
    String result = "";
    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
        BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(0);

        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
        } 
        else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
            result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());

    }
    return result;
}
```

I understand how the multipart work. But I don't understand how in this function, the form that gets the string into the objet multipart works?
I am using that and it is working fine to get the string.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/javadoc/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent%28%29 - Check this doc.In your code `bodyPart.getContent()` will return the string.

Comment: I'm not quite sure which part you're confused about.  JavaMail uses the JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF, javax.activation) to figure out how to convert from a MIME type to a Java object.  Is that the part you don't understand?

Comment: @BillShannon hello bill thx for answer, the part that i am confused is with the recursive call in the elseif that is the part who takes the text into the mime objet but i dont understand how thx !!

Comment: If the first body part is text, it just returns it.  If the first body part is another multipart, it recurses.  This can happen if you have a multipart/related nested inside a multipart/mixed, for example.  This doesn't handle all possible cases, but it handles many common cases.